# SQL get recently modified post for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[posts]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_posted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [date_modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [content] [text] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_posts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [id] ASC )
)
```

My company needs a single query that will get the post id of the most recently modified post for each user. Can anyone please help me? Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? And are you sure you're using mySQL? This looks more like SQL Server syntax to me.

Comment: oops, so this is SQL , that why I look at mySQL and I have no idea about this =.=!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rank()` function should do the trick:

```
SELECT user_id, id AS most_recent_post_id
FROM   (SELECT user_id, 
               id, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_posted DESC) AS rk
        FROM   [posts]) p
WHERE  rk = 1
```